# How to fetch a specific field from axios post API request

Tags: node.js, axios, mocha.js

I am using the below piece of code

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios
  .post('https://xxx', {
    "audience": "http://xxxx",
    "grant_type": "xxxxx",
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxx"
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

And I wanted assign the "res.data.token" to a variable token and use the variable in below code

```
describe('/GET device information', function () {
  it("it should GET a Good Auth Status", function(done) {
    chai.request('http:xxxxxx')
      .get('xxxxxxxxxxxx')
      .set({ "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` })
      .then((res) => {
         (res).should.have.status(200);
         // console.log(body) - not really needed, but I include them as a comment
        done();
      }).catch((err) => done(err))
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap it in a try/catch and destructure the object:

```js
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('https://xxx', {
        'audience': 'http://xxxx',
        'grant_type': 'xxxxx',
        'client_id': 'xxxxx',
        'client_secret': 'xxxxx'
      })
      const { data, token, foo, bar, status } = res.data
      (status).should.equal(200)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
}
```

quick example